# Prove that $(a,m) = 1$ iff there exists an integer $n$ such that $na \equiv 1 \pmod m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Prove that $(a,m)=1$ iff there exists an integer $n$ such that $na \equiv 1 \pmod m$

How do I go about this problem?

Comment: What? How do you expect a condition on $x$ and $y$ to be equivalent to one on $a$ and $m$?

Comment: What is a? What is m?

Comment: Shosh, be more careful when copying questions: you seem to have mixed up a,m,x,y...

Comment: Shosh, it looks as though if you're given $na \equiv 1 \mod m$ that $n$ and $a$ are modular inverses of each other modulo $m$. I'm assuming you meant to show that $(n,a) = 1$?

Comment: sorry, now i fixed it

Comment: Shos, edit also your question's title...

Comment: Just corrected the title

Comment: @PeterTamaroff What you claim is only true for $d=1$. For instance, $2\cdot 3+(-2)\cdot 2=2$, but $(2,3)=1$.

Comment: @julien Darn. I correct here:  
Recall that that $(a,b)=1$ if and only if there exist integers $x,y$ such that $ax+by=1$. Note that modding out by $x$ you get that $by≡1 \mod x$, and the same for $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure you can prove the following steps:

$$(a,m)=1\Longleftrightarrow \,\,\exists\,\,n,y\in\Bbb Z\,\,\,s.t.\,\,\,na+ym=1\Longleftrightarrow na=1-ym\Longleftrightarrow na=1\pmod m$$

Comment: Remark that one way to prove the first equivalence is to note that it is a special case of the [Bezout identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_identity) for the gcd. There are also other methods. What works best depends on how one's number theory course is organized.

Answer (score 3):

As Don wrote, one way is by  [Bezout's gcd identity.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)  Another is by Euclid's Lemma and pigeonholes.

$\rm(1)\,\ \ (a,m) = 1\Rightarrow\,$ the map $\rm\,x\to ax\,$ is $\,1$-$1\,$ on $\,\rm\Bbb Z/m\, = $ integers $\rm\,mod\ m,\,$ since $\rm\,ax \equiv ay\:\Rightarrow\:m\mid a(x-y)\:\Rightarrow\:m\mid x-y\Rightarrow x\equiv y,\:$ by Euclid's Lemma.

$\rm(2) \ \ x\to ax\:$ is $\,1$-$1\,$ so onto, by the Pigeonhole/box principle, since $\rm\:\Bbb Z/m\:$ is finite

$\rm(3)\ \ x\to ax\:$ is onto $\,\Rightarrow$ $\rm\:ax\equiv 1\:$ for some $\rm\,x.\quad$ **QED**

Comment: Damn, I liked this one! +1

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Ireland and Rosen's "Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory," the pages 30 - 33 give a very readable presentation to the general congruence problem:

$ax \equiv b \pmod m$